# Cors error.. Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: flask, cors

I am trying XHR GET request on a python-flask based API and getting this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://..... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

The server code:

```
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_cors import CORS
application_root = config.get_application_root()
static_folder = os.path.join(application_root, 'static')
template_folder = os.path.join(application_root, 'templates')
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static',         static_folder=static_folder, template_folder=template_folder)

cors = CORS(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] ='mysql://*********'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True # To allow flask propagating  exception even if debug is set to false on app^M
api = Api(app)

@app.after_request

def after_request(response):
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
   response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
   return response

api.add_resource(TestResults, '/results')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   db.init_app(app)
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)  # important to mention debug=True^M
```

The response header still doesn't get the required header.

```
Content-Length  2452
Content-Type      application/json
Date      Tue, 06 Nov 2018 06:52:06 GMT
Server  Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.4.7
```

What am I missing here...

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? (Use browser devtools to check.) Is the response a response to the GET request from your code or is it instead a response to a COR preflight OPTIONS request (sent automatically by the browser)?

Comment: Status code: 200 OK
Version: HTTP/1.0
Response headers (180 B) 
Allow 
OPTIONS, HEAD, GET
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=utf-8
Server 
Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.4.7
Request headers (544 B) 
Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers 
access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Request-Method 
GET
Connection 
Origin 
http://0.0.0.0:8081
User-Agent

Comment: the XHR is a "OPTIONS" response if I use fetch API with method: 'get', mode: 'cors', headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', Accept: 'application/json' } but it is of type "GET" if I send a regular XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You definitely don’t want to be adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to the request. Remove that. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is strictly a response header. And unless something breaks if you omit Accept: 'application/json'  from the request, then don’t add it. Without your code trying to set those headers, the browser don’t do an OPTIONS request. It’ll just do a GET request.

Comment: So if you do a regular XMLHttpRequest without setting those request headers, and the GET request gets made, what’s the status code of the response to that GET? If it’s 200 OK but doesn’t contain the Access-Control-Allow-\* response headers, then yeah it’d seem your flask code isn’t actually sending the response headers as expected. But it’s still possible you may be getting a cached response from the browser, from before you added the response headers on the server. So it’s worth force-reloading/clearing your cache. And/or trying with a different browser.

Comment: correct, I added that to me request before I knew that it has to be added to the response instead... I removed it and now its a GET request but the error persists.

Comment: I get 200 OK but response header doesnt contain Access-Control-Allow-*... I tried a different browser & cleared cache on Firefox.. still the same error.. I dont see the response header added on get response headers